# Is there a unified login?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I'm a Stack Overflow member. When I go to other Stack Exchange sites, there's a button to "Join this community." However, that leads you to a full sign-up screen. You can sign up using your Facebook account, but I don't see a way to sign in with my Stack Overflow account.

I can understand not being a member of *all* Stack Exchange communities *automatically* just by joining just one, but I would hope there'd be a way to join several without having to create separate accounts for each. Is there?

Comment: _"but I would hope there'd be a way to join several without having to create separate accounts for each. Is there?"_ In short: No, there isn't.

Comment: I recommend reading this https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260153/213575

Comment: Are you sure you were logged in to Stack Overflow at the time? Upon clicking 'Join this community', you *should* be presented with the following box to have your account created and linked in one click. Here's what I see on my sock: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgOYN.png

Comment: @Rob I vaguely remember this but IIRC, it used to be possible to have a profile on one of the sites without having a global SE account (not sure if I described this correctly) and the site would ask you if you want to opt-in to creating an SE account or just log in "regularly". Apparently, the latter has not been an available option for quite some time but IDK if the former option had been enforced on all _existing_ users at some point...

Comment: ...Now, since the OP seems to have been around for a while (>8 years), I'm wondering if they have never opted in for that option, then clicking `Join this community` would perhaps behave differently for them? -- On a related note, and although I agree with your comment, it's probably worth mentioning that if the user isn't logged in, the button should say `Sign up` instead of `Join this community`.

Comment: Could you check your login on [My Logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current) and mention what services are you using? Facebook login? Stack Exchange login? Just want to make sure unless you're using OpenID which is already deprecated by SE... (might be related, might not)

Comment: I sign up with my Google account, 2 clicks and I'm a member :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That's not how it's ever worked. You can either participate unregistered (cookie-based account) or register an account. But *both* of those options still create a network account behind the scenes. You're probably mistaking the unregistered "would you like to fully register your account" email for something else.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed You're probably thinking about when they changed the front-end and some of the back-end to provide universal SSO support. The account type didn't, iirc, have to change to permit this; it was merely a convenience system.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, that's probably it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I sure wish all answers were as succinct and final as yours! :)

Comment: as a side note: when you get enough reputation and join other communities, you are a "trusted" user and are awarded +100 points. this normally is enough rep to start being active on the other sites.

Comment: I remember before having joined several communities in one click when being logged to Stack Overflow, as stated by someone above. It no longer works and I am looking for why not, I guess it may be related to Chrome blocking third party cookies.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're not being recognized as a logged in user on a site for whatever reason, you'll need to find your way to the login page (`/users/login`) somehow.

There, you just type in your email address and password like you would on any other site. You don't need to register on each individual site, your same credentials will work on all of them, even if you don't have a profile there yet.

Once logged in, if you don't have a profile yet on that site, it will ask you to confirm creating a profile there.

As far as why the "Join this community" button would redirect you to the signup page, it sounds like there might be something messed up with your cookies. We'd recommend simply logging out fully (via the Stack Exchange button at the top right) and logging in again to completely refresh your session.

As always, if we mess something up badly and need help with your account, feel free to [contact us](/contact).